# Azure DevOps Agent Pool Security

Tags: azure-devops

I am having a hard time understanding how the Agent Pool security for a Team Project works or is populated. I think I am missing a basic construct.

I would like to grant the following access rights at the Project Level:

> Contributors - role: User
>   Project Mini Administrators (custom group) - role: Administrator

Here is what I did:
From *Project settings*, I clicked on *Agent Pools* and then the *Security* button.
I added the two above referenced groups.

[image: Agent Pool Security for Project]
If I then click on one of the Agent Pools listed on this screen and select *Security*, I can see that Inheritance is on but my new groups are not listed for the selected Pool.

What am I missing? If a Contributor or Project Mini Administrator go to a Build Definition in the Team Project and attempt to drop down the Agent list, they do not see any of the Agents; as if they had no security to the Agents. If I manually add the to all of the Agents individually, they things work as expected. Its almost as if the inheritance chain from the Agent Pool Security to the Agent is not propagating.

[image: Agent]

Comment: Why do your screen shots say "You do not have permission to edit roles for this resource"?

Comment: Because I accessed the screens using an account that does not have maintenance capability. If I go in as the Project Administrator I obviously do not see that message.

Comment: Everything I've tried produces the same result as you are seeing. Maybe this is an issue to send to MS. I see too that the only groups being handled appropriately with **Inheritance=on** are the default Project, Release, and Build Administrator groups.

Comment: Depending on what you're using the **Mini Admin** group for, you could add that group into the Admin group and it would tag along as part of the Project Admin's **Administrator** role. Users and groups you add to the Mini Admin group would then receive the Deny permission for things they shouldn't inherit from their membership in PA. Not pretty, but maybe a workaround.

Comment: I am glad you can confirm the same behavior. Makes me feel like I am not missing something obvious. I've been burned in the past with **Deny** privs and generally try to avoid using them where possible so the piggyback of the **Mini Admins** into the **Project Administrators** is not really feasible. It also does not solve my **Contributors** issue.

Comment: I wonder if you can get what you need by using the Organization level role assignments? I just had something similar happen with my deployment group role settings and I had to resolve a conflict between the deployment pool (organization level) and the deployment group(s) to allow a sub-group of users to register new targets to the pool and group. It's not quite the same, as I'm seeing the role inheritance working in that area but not with agent pools, but maybe the inheritance works at the org level.

Comment: That would be a challenge because I would have to go back to the organization level every time I added a new Team Project and potentially add it's groups. I am reaching out to Microsoft for an answer. If/when I hear back I will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided feedback for this problem on [Microsoft's Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/553668/azure-devops-agent-pool-security-on-project.html) site. Microsoft confirmed that this was an issue and is working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops#security), there is (was) and **All Agents** node that would assign the selected user the specified role for all agent pools.

With the new layout of portions of the project settings UI, this node is accessed via the **Security** button on the **Agent Pools** landing page where all pools for the project are listed.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Role assignment for a specific pool should happen from the security view of that pool.

[image]

Looking at the Agent Pool security for the entire organization will show you the older UI that is more consistent with the vocabulary of the documentation.

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I have done, but the permissions are not propagating down to the Agents from the Pool settings. I updated my question above with screenshots.